# SQL: Counting common elements

Tags: mysql, sql, count

I'm trying to come up with a table that displays the total number of common elements in a table.

For example. I have a table A with values:

```
colName
=============
a
b
b
c
c
c
d
```

Is there any way that I can come up with a result that displays:

```
colName totalCount
==================
a        1
b        2
c        3
d        1
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a simple query using an aggregate function `COUNT` and `GROUP BY` clause.

```
SELECT   colName, COUNT(colName) totalCount
FROM     tableName
GROUP BY colName
```

`totalCount` is called the **ALIAS** of `COUNT(colName)`